# Determine what UMDF driver is consuming CPU resources in Host Process

Tags: windows, performance, troubleshooting

In task manager I see significant CPU usage from `Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework Host Process`.

How do I determine the actual driver or device that is responsible for this?

Comment: You mean `wudf.exe`? I would try process explorer from sysinternals. Double click the process, look at the threads and double click the one using the most cpu to view the call stack. If you do this a few times, you might see a pattern where a driver is always present in the call stack of the busiest thread.